How to handle multiple in-app purchase subscription from one (Same) device In flutter
App Is built In flutter version 3.22.0 and we have used in-app-purchase package version 3.2.0
Issue Is I've registered Into app and purchased one subscription after that logout and again register with different user In app and trying to purchase subscription but at this time it throws error like below:
Andriod Error Message
IOS Error Message
Multiple time in-app purchase subscription should work with same productID with different user In same device.

It sounds like the problem is you are not changing the apple id when you make purchase.
In production users will have their own user account and apple id.
The solution would be to make more test flight accounts so can simulate a different user with a different apple id
